# If add <style>...</style> to <head> section, fails "Something went wrong" msg and the error.log lists the first property

Tags: python, css, flask, pythonanywhere

If add `<style>...</style>` to `<head>` section, it fails with a "Something went wrong" msg and the `error.log` lists the first property as causing the error.

If `<style=..` added the to a `<p>` code property it works. 
If try using a .css file no error/no impact.

working with modified version of the introductory demo in PythonAnywhere blog.

If `<style=..` added the to a `<p>` code property it works. 
If try using a .css file no error/no impact.

```py
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        h1 {color: red;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Expected: header will be printed in red, centered on page

Actual: receive "Something went wrong" msg.  error.log states KeyError:'color'

Comment: It sounds like the HTML is being interpreted as Python code, or as a template.  Which tutorial blog post are you following?  Does it use templates, or is the HTML specified in strings inside the Python code?

Comment: Thanks. Uses css inside <style> property. Uses PA’s intro to flask. Will send url on Monday. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe drop us a line at support@pythonanywhere.com so that we can help over email -- if you give us permission, we can look at your files, which might help us help you work out what is wrong.

Comment: I will follow up Monday via email.